# Conditional check for Json array in Karate framework

Tags: json, arraylist, foreach, karate, json-arrayagg

Want to validate in Karate framework
For the below Json What I want to validate is,

if "isfilter_regex":0 then "msgtype": "##regex ^[A-Za-z0-9_.]*-*/*"
or if "isfilter_regex":1 then "msgtype": "#string"
(when isfilter_regex = 1 then msgtype must be a regular expression)

In my case number of candidate s in candidates array is 180+
I tried lot of things I ended up failing can anybody help me here?

```
{
   "candidates":[
      {
         "candidate":{
            "name":"Alex",
            "category":[
               {
                  "category_name":"APCMRQ",
                  "filters":[
                     {
                        "isfilter_regex":0,
                        "msgtype":"APCMRQ"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "category_name":"BIDBRQ",
                  "filters":[
                     {
                        "isfilter_regex":1,
                        "msgtype":"'(AMSCNQ(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}){0,3})'"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I normally reply to questions where the example is simplified focusing on what the problem is. also please see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+array+conditional

Comment: What I want to check is,
When "isfilter_regex": 0 then "msgtype": '##regex ^[A-Za-z0-9.\/\\s_\-]* '
And when "isfilter_regex": 1 then "msgtype": '#string '

I agree, sorry about that.
Just wanted to show the complexity, so I took this approach.

Comment: if you can edit your question to be a 10-line example or less I'll look at it tomorrow

Comment: I have done edits, please have a look Sir

Answer (score 0):

I tried below way which works only when idex specified, but what to do if I want to do this check for entire array?,

```
* def msgRegexValue = response.candidates[150].candidate.category[0].filters[0].isfilter_regex
* def actualFilter = response.candidates[150].candidate.category[0].filters[0]
* def expectedFilter = actualFilter

    * def withRegex =
    """
    {
       "isfilter_regex": 0,
       "msgtype": '##regex ^[A-Za-z0-9_.]*-*/*'
    }
    """
    * def withoutRegex =
    """
    {
       "isfilter_regex": 1,
       "msgtype": '##string'
    }
    """
    * def expected = msgRegexValue == 0 ? withRegex: withoutRegex
    * match actualFilter == expected
```